# Duplicate sites created

Tags: flow

I have a flow that tries to create a site with the http request:
[image]

The result is a success:
[image]

However I get this everytime I run it, when it should return a 4 (Duplicate site) on subsequent runs.
Is there something I'm missing?

**Note**
I have a workaround, by making an additional HTTP request to _api/SPSiteManager/Status first, to check the site exists. However I would still like to find an answer to this question, so I can remove these couple of superfluous steps from my flow.

Comment: How long are you waiting before the flow is run again? (After the first flow)

Comment: @CallumCrowley I've run the flow many times, from 5 minutes after it was first created (yesterday), to at least 2 times today (over 24 hours afterwards), but it still gives a SiteStatus of 2.

Comment: Is it actually creating duplicate sites in SharePoint? Can you check from SharePoint admin center, at least URLs will be different for newly created sites?

Comment: @GaneshSanap No, it's not actually creating duplicate sites, or new sites with a suffix.